# size() function on request.resource map isn't what I expect

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Using Firestore rules i'm trying to ensure that the incoming request, which is a map object, only has 1 entry (i.e. only 1 key). Using .size() == 1 always results in insufficient permissions, while doing .size() > 1 is always right.

The request comes from this:

```
const batch = this.db.firestore.batch();
batch.update(frameUserRef, {
    [`users.${this.authService.currentUser.uid}.pictureCount`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
});
batch.commit();
```

And I'm attempting to use a firestore rule such as

```
request.resource.data.users.keys().size() == 1

// NOTE: This doesn't work either
request.resource.data.users.size() == 1
```

However, this never results in true as I would expect. I am trying to prevent someone from attaching another update in this call i.e.

```
const batch = this.db.firestore.batch();
batch.update(frameUserRef, {
    [`users.${this.authService.currentUser.uid}.pictureCount`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
    [`users.${ANOTHER_USER_ID_HERE}.pictureCount`].pictureCount: 100000 // MALICIOUS REQUEST
});
batch.commit();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I misunderstanding the .size() function? Any info is appreciated.

**EDIT:** After more testing, it seems the `.size()` is the size of the map currently in the Firestore (i.e. the map has 4 entries already, I'm trying to only update one, and .size() == 4). It doesn't seem to come from the request like I would image `request.resource.data` to pull from....
Anyone have insight on this?

Comment: Why are you trying to constrain the update of an object field to just one property at a time, when the end result can clearly contain multiple properties? What exactly is the condition you're trying to prevent?

Comment: FYI you don't need a batch if you have just a single document operation in it.  You use batches when you have multiple documents to change, and they all must change at the exact same time.